# Node.js API design and route handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, api-design

I am not really sure what to title this, but I'm new to `Node.js`. I just found a neat REST API project on GitHub to implement but I'm not sure how I can split all GET and POST etc. to separate files.

I have one singular `api.js` file where I have

```
function API_ROUTER(router, connection, md5) {
    var self = this;
    self.handleRoutes(router, connection, md5);
}

API_ROUTER.prototype.handleRoutes = function(router, connection, md5) {
    router.get("/", function(req, res) {
        res.json({"Message" : "Hello World !"});
    });
};

module.exports = API_ROUTER;
```

Now how can I create a sibling `other.js` and use:

```
var api = require('./api.js');

// Create router.get, router.post etc. here?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I'm not sure how I can split all GET and POST etc. to separate files.

One way you can organize your routes would be to have a separate object for each route that has the handlers (separated by HTTP methods) and other needed info such as the path:

api/home.js

```
module.exports =  {
   path: '/',
   handlers: {
     'get': function(req, res) {
          res.json({"Message" : "Hello World !"});
      },
      'post': { 
        // ...
      }
      // ...
    }
}
```

api/other.js

```
module.exports =  {
   path: '/other',
   handlers: {
     'get': function(req, res) {
        res.json({"Message" : "Other !"});
      },
    // ...
```

Then you can load all of these inside the `handleRoutes` method:

```
API_ROUTER.prototype.handleRoutes = function(router, connection, md5) {
   var routes = ['home', 'other'];

   routes.forEach(function(name) {
     // load the current route object (NOTE: you should use the path module for determining file path in a cross-platform manner)
     var routeObject = require('./' + name + '.js');

     var apiPath = routeObject.path;
     var handlers = routeObject.handlers;
     var methods = Object.keys(handlers);

     // assign handlers for each method
     methods.forEach(function(method) {
       router[method](apiPath, handlers[method]);
     });

   });
};
```

This will install all your routes with the appropriate information and handlers.
Now you can call this code by instantiating your `API_ROUTER` with the necessary data:

```
// initialize the api (and handle the routes internally)
var Api = new require('./api.js')(router, connection, md5);
```

Comment: You forgot to add  +'.js' to routeObject variable. Otherwise this is a working solution and I'll be implementing it!

Comment: @Rcls nodejs automatically adds `.js`. I would not add the `.js` suffix at all, because the advantage of using a suffix less `require` is that you could replace your file with a _module_ later (e.g. if you need to split the code in smaller chunks).

Comment: Thanks for the info! I actually changed the module.exports to a  function so I can pass the connection param to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you implement a RESTful API, then you should keep in mind that this is just one way how you can provide data, and you might want to change it in future, as of that the API will most of the time only be a translation layer.

Normally you will split your code based on the resources, and the code that is handling the request won't have so much logic, it will just take the request and pass it to you internal API. For that purpose you not really need an additional layer if you already use `express.js` or a similar library.

In express the [`app.use([path,] function [, function...])`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use), already provides the functionality you would need to modularize your code. For each resource your will create an own `express.Router` that itself also might mount another sub module. So for this part you do not really need a library.

When might a library be useful:

- if it automatically translates thrown errors to the correct response codes
- if it includes a tool to automatically create a documentation to your API
- if it fully abstracts the underlaying routing system so that you can hook into `express`, `hapi`, ... without the need to change the code.

Here how a setup with `express.js` could look like

**./lib/rest/customer.js**

```
var customerSystem = require('../customer-system');
var express = require('express');
var router = new express.Router();

router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  customerSystem.find({
    id: req.params.id
  }, function(err, customer) {
    if (err) {
      res.status( /*correct status code*/ ).send( /*depending on the api return json, xml, ....*/ )
    } else {
      res.send( /*depending on the api return json, xml, ....*/ )
    }
  })
});

router.delete('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  customerSystem.delete({
    id: req.params.id
  }, function(err) {
    //...
  });
});


router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  //...
});

//save the customer id for the pass to the sub routers
router.use('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  req.customerId = req.params.id;
  next();
});

router.use('/:id/addresses', require('./customer-address') )

module.exports = router;
```

**./lib/rest/customer-address.js**

```
var customerSystem = require('../customer-system');
var express = require('express');
var router = new express.Router();

router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  customerSystem.find({
    id: req.customerId
  }, function(err, customer) {
   // ...
  })
});

/* ..... */

//save the address id for the pass to the sub routers
router.use('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  req.addressId = req.params.id;
  next();
});

router.use('/:id/addresses', require('./customer-address') )

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Actually from this I kinda figured out what you meant. It's much simpler to do it like this, yes, I admit. What I did was created a 'var router = express.Router()' in server.js, which I then pass onto require('./api/test')(router, connection). Now I can just require all needed route files in server.js and have all I need. Thanks, these answers really help me understand how node works.